# Why is _POST Not Collecting Data From HTML Form?

Tags: html, forms, php-5.6

I'm trying to make a contact form for my website and I can't get the data in the HTML form to post to anywhere?

I've done a bit of research and learned that in order for a form to be able to "POST", the form must have an input or button tag with type="submit" and a valid name, while the Form must have a method attribute such as, method="POST".

I've also tested to see if the _POST array is collecting any data using:
`print_r($_POST);` the array is always empty. Below I've included some code that makes a form and when you click submit the form data is posted and neatly displayed. **This code is not mine**, the code is tested and working from `http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-check-if-the-submit-button-is-clicked-in-PHP.php`, **I included it here to demonstrate that for some reason working and tested code will still give me errors.**

I'm running PHP through localhost using Wampserver.

Maintainer / Upgrade to 2.5 by Herve Leclerc
Upgrade to 3 by Otomatic (wampserver@otomatic.net)
Multi styles for homepage by Jojaba
Installer by Inno Setup: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php
Forum Wampserver: http://forum.wampserver.com/index.php
 Versions used:
Apache 2.4.37 Port 80- PHP 7.2.1
MySQL 5.7.24 Port 3306
MariaDB 10.3.12 Port 3307
PHP 5.6.40 for CLI (Command-Line Interface)

Here is the tested and working code

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<label>Enter Your Name Please:</label>
<input type="text"name=" name_entered" value='<?php echo $name; ?>'/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php

$name= $_POST['name_entered'];
$submitbutton= $_POST['submitbutton'];

if ($submitbutton){
if (!empty($name)) {
echo 'The name you entered is ' . $name;
}
else {
echo 'You did not enter a name. Please enter a name into this form     field.';
}
}
?>
```

and my output:

```
Enter Your Name Please: 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp64\www\Practice\index.php       on line 3
Call Stack
#
Time 1
Memory 0.0001
Function 403584
Location {main}( )
...\index.php:0
'/>


The name you entered is 'example name'
```

My question is does this error only happen when running on my system and if that is the case what could be done to fix the issue. Also is this the correct way of coding a POSTable form? Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple form example

The example below displays a simple HTML form with two input fields and a submit button:

```
 <html>
<body>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When the user fills out the form above and clicks the submit button, the form data is sent for processing to a PHP file named "welcome.php". The form data is sent with the HTTP POST method.

To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables. The "welcome.php" looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The same result could also be achieved using the HTTP GET method:

```
 <html>
<body>

<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and "welcome_get.php" looks like this:

```
 <html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

GET vs. POST

Both GET and POST create an array (e.g. array( key1 => value1, key2 => value2, key3 => value3, ...)). This array holds key/value pairs, where keys are the names of the form controls and values are the input data from the user.

Both GET and POST are treated as $_GET and $_POST. These are superglobals, which means that they are always accessible, regardless of scope - and you can access them from any function, class or file without having to do anything special.

$_GET is an array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

$_POST is an array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
When to use GET?

Information sent from a form with the GET method is visible to everyone (all variable names and values are displayed in the URL). GET also has limits on the amount of information to send. The limitation is about 2000 characters. However, because the variables are displayed in the URL, it is possible to bookmark the page. This can be useful in some cases.

GET may be used for sending non-sensitive data.

Note: GET should NEVER be used for sending passwords or other sensitive information!
When to use POST?

Information sent from a form with the POST method is invisible to others (all names/values are embedded within the body of the HTTP request) and has no limits on the amount of information to send.

Moreover POST supports advanced functionality such as support for multi-part binary input while uploading files to server.

Source https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the $name variable before you echo it out on the input.  After submit, it should have a value and display in both the input and on the return string. That is if I didn't misunderstand this question.

Also edited the action attribute, this will set it to specifically post to the current page.

```
Example: action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
```

Although this will fail the W3 validation checker. Some alternatives are to set it to the name of the page you are working with or `action="#"` etc.

```
<?php 

$name= $_POST['name_entered'];
$submitbutton= $_POST['submitbutton'];

?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
<label>Enter Your Name Please:</label>
<input type="text"name=" name_entered" value='<?php echo $name; ?>'/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if ($submitbutton){
if (!empty($name)) {
echo 'The name you entered is ' . $name;
}
else {
echo 'You did not enter a name. Please enter a name into this form     field.';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that worked for me. For some reason the HTML tag button does not work correctly in my case, I had to use an input tag of type submit, and the input tag had to have an assigned value. Thank you for your help on this everyone.